# How to make Maven download only the POM files for all (transitive) dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm currently using the [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) like

```
mvn -B dependency:copy-dependencies \
    -Dmdep.copyPom=true \
    -DoutputDirectory="$OUTDIR"
```

to download all POMs of all (transitive) dependencies. However, that is *also* downloading the JARs, which I don't want. I tried to use `includeTypes` / `excludeTypes` to limit to POM files only, but that didn't work as nothing is retrieved then.

Is there another option / command that really just retrieves the POMs?

Background: I only need the meta-data from all transitive POMs for compliance checks.

Comment: Curiosity and further context: why do you want only the poms? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: according to [doc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#copyPom) , it says _"Also copy the pom of each artifact."_ , looks like the main purpose of this plugin is to copy artifact not the pom.

Comment: Context: Ultimately I do want to download the source code of all transitive dependencies, but from SCM (for provenance analysis reasons), not from `-sources` artifacts. For that, I'm calling [scm:checkout](https://maven.apache.org/components/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkout-mojo.html) in a post-processing step.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating an Open Source project that downloads and gathers metadata from Maven builds, and actually [several other build systems](https://github.com/oss-review-toolkit/ort#analyzer), too. It's called [OSS Review Toolkit](https://github.com/oss-review-toolkit/ort) (ORT for short) and programmatically uses the [maven-resolver](https://github.com/apache/maven-resolver) library to download only the POMs to analyze their contained metadata.